# using trace() command in Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

New AS3/Flash Builder user here. I'm debugging an AS3 project using Flash Builder 4.5, and debug version of Flash plug-in in Firefox. I'm using a trace() command, but it's not outputting anything in the Console window of Flash Builder (is that where it's supposed to place stuff?). However, I'm wondering why the trace() command is even needed because the Variables tab in the debug perspective contains all the variable values anyway. Is the trace() command redundant or otherwise useful somehow in this environment, or is it intended for command line debugging, etc. (non-Flash Builder environment). Any light someone can shed on this would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be outputting the trace statements to the console window of Flash Builder.  here are a few things to check:

1. Do you have a debug version of the Flash player installed?
2. Did you launch the app from Flash Builder using the "Debug" button?

It would be extremely odd to me that the trace would not output to the Flash Builder Console window; but you can see all the variables in the variables tab.  Something seems amiss.

Comment: Hi Flextras, you're right, it's working fine. My problem was I had a lot of variables, each on a different line, in the trace statement and I stopped in the middle of the trace statement expecting to see the variables in the Console that I passed. Actually, they only show when the trace statement's ")" is reached.